# Null safe concatenation of two nullable list of items

Tags: java, list

I'm trying to add two nullable list using below:

```
List<Employee> employees = null;
if (<some condition>) {
    employees = employeeService.getEmployees(<some criteria>);

    // Add another list of employees
    if (<some condition>) {
        List<Employee> employeesSubList = employeeService.getEmployees(<some other criteria>));
        if (!isEmpty(employeesSubList)) {
            if (!isEmpty(employees)) {
                employees.addAll(employeesSubList);
            } else {
                employees = employeesSubList;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works but the code looks horribly ugly. There is a hard condition that the parent `List<Employee> employees` will be null instead of empty list in case no employees are present.
Is there a cleaner way to do the same?

I tried Java 8 approach but IntelliJ throws some warnings on `.orElse(emptyList()).addAll(employeesSubList)`:

```
List<Employee> employees = null;
if (<some condition>) {
    employees = employeeService.getEmployees(<some criteria>);

    // Add another list of employees
    if (<some condition>) {
        List<Employee> employeesSubList = employeeService.getEmployees(<some other criteria>));
        if (!isEmpty(employeesSubList)) {
            Optional.ofNullable(employees).orElse(emptyList()).addAll(employeesSubList);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does your service return null? Why can't you make it always return empty lists? Or throw exceptions when "criteria" is not met?

Comment: This is because I'm working with some crazy  consumer who expects a null response instead of empty list.

Comment: Use empty lists for all internal calculations, and special-case check for empty lists and replace them with null at the API boundary. That way, the code is easier to write *and* if you ever find a smarter consumer who wants the same problem solved but with the right API, the change request will be trivial.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel that's exactly what I've done finally. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "problem" Intellij is probably telling you is that `emptyList().addAll()` is 1) an error because that's an immutable list 2) is never assigned to anything, and it returns a boolean, so you need a different way to get that data

Plus, you could get rid of the if statement because adding an empty list to another list is a no-op

For example

```
// assumes employees is not null 
employees.addAll(
    Optional.ofNullable(employeeService.getEmployees(<some other criteria>))).orElse(emptyList())
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there a cleaner way?

IMO no.

- You could argue that testing for `null` is cleaner than calling an `isEmpty` method, but I'm not convinced.
- You could argue that hiding the `null` tests behind an `Optional` is cleaner, but I'm not convinced.

---

But the real problem is this:

> There is a hard condition that the parent List employees will be null instead of empty list.

That is what is causing you to have to deal with the null-safety issue.  The clean solution is to use an empty list; i.e. a list with no elements.

Then you can rewrite your example code as:

```
List<Employee> employees = Collections.emptyList();
if (<some condition>) {
    employees = employeeService.getEmployees(<some criteria>);

    // Add another list of employees
    if (<some condition>) {
        List<Employee> employeesSubList = employeeService.getEmployees(<some other criteria>));
        if (!employees.isEmpty()) {
            employees.addAll(employeesSubList);
        } else {
            employees = employeesSubList;
        }
    }
}
```

(Note: if you use Collections.emptyList(), be aware that it returns an *immutable* list.  So you can't add elements to it.  The alternative is to use `new ArrayList<>()` to create a mutable list that is initially empty.)

In short, if you want "clean" you are looking the wrong part of your code-base. IMO.

Comment: okay... I've changed it to return a list instead of null in the business layer to have a cleaner code all around. Then transformed it to null right before sending it back to the user.